# SQL TRIGGER EVENT FOR PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers, eventtrigger

I'm developing with PHP + MySQL.

I need to delete a row (tuple) in a table when the expiration date occurs.

Probably the best way be a Trigger but I have no idea how to do it.

Somebody have an example?

Comment: When should this happen? On a specific time, then an update on the record occurs. Triggered by your application? Depending on that this can be realized with an Event, Trigger or Procedure.

Comment: Consider using the [event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html) instead. This seems me the best solution for expiration dates.

Comment: the expiration date is a field on my table.

Comment: Specifically I have a table that stores student enrollment.
if the student does not validate their registration within 24, I want to delete this row.
I store the (registration time + 24 hours) in the table in a field "endDate".
So, When "endDate" occurs I have to delete this row.

Comment: Have you got some example about "event scheduler" ?

Comment: Have a look at the manual, i.e. [CREATE EVENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html). Is it too difficult to find the relevant pages?

Comment: Is the first time for me I do "event scheduler".
Sorry, but this is too different for me.
Thanks for you help and your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use MySQLs [event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html). The minimal example of the manual page of [CREATE EVENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html) would be a good base for that what you probably need:

```
 CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;
```

If you want to clean up every 10 minutes you would use

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 MINUTE
```

And your clearing statement would be a DELETE:

```
    DO
      DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE expiration_date < NOW();
```

That's all and MySQL will do it automatically every 10 minutes. Complete in four lines of SQL:

```
CREATE EVENT clear_expirations             -- a better name for the event
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 MINUTE         -- as you need it
    DO
      DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE expiration_date < NOW();
```

**Edit**

Per default the event scheduler will be stopped:

> The global **event_scheduler** system variable determines whether the
>   Event Scheduler is enabled and running on the server. It has one of
>   these 3 values, which affect event scheduling as described here:
>
> **OFF**: The Event Scheduler is stopped. The event scheduler thread does
>   not run, is not shown in the output of SHOW PROCESSLIST, and no
>   scheduled events are executed. OFF is the default value for
>   event_scheduler.
>
> When the Event Scheduler is stopped (event_scheduler is OFF), it can
>   be started by setting the value of event_scheduler to ON. (See next
>   item.)
>
> **ON**: The Event Scheduler is started; the event scheduler thread runs
>   and executes all scheduled events.
>
> ...
>
> **DISABLED**: This value renders the Event Scheduler nonoperational. When
>   the Event Scheduler is DISABLED, the event scheduler thread does not
>   run (and so does not appear in the output of SHOW PROCESSLIST). In
>   addition, the Event Scheduler state cannot be changed at runtime.

You can get the value of this system variable with

```
SELECT @@event_scheduler;
```

If the result is `OFF` you can start the event scheduler with

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 'ON';
```

You should modify the configuration of your MySQL server, so that the event scheduler will be running at the start of the mysqld process.

It should be clear, that you got to be administrator of your MySQL server to modify this configuration.

Comment: This is my code exactly: (My code is located in the same file as CREATE TABLE. Is this correct?)
<\n>
     `CREATE EVENT clear_expirations`
     `ON SCHEDULE`
         `EVERY 1 MINUTE`
         `DO`
     `DELETE FROM `#__anual`` `WHERE end_date <= NOW();`

But does nothing. My table remains the same. What can be happening?

(I don't writ "AT" before "EVERY" because I want to do this always every X minutes).

Thanks for your example. It's very valuable.

Comment: @DominicS You spotted my slackness in modifying the example code, great! I've edited my answer. Please have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-privileges.html and look at `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS WHERE EVENT_NAME='clear_expirations' AND EVENT_SCHEMA='your database name';`

Comment: `GRANT EVENT ON systemadmin.* TO xxx@xxx.systemadmin.es;`

`event_scheduler=on`

`mysql> SET GLOBAL event_scheduler=on;`

and your `SELECT` is OK, but does nothing.

Comment: What's the result of `select @@event_scheduler;`? If it's value is `off`, then the event scheduler won't do anything. You can set it with `set global event_scheduler = 'ON';`

Comment: The result of select @@event_scheduler; is ON

Comment: What's the result of `SELECT last_executed FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS WHERE EVENT_NAME='clear_expiration' AND EVENT_SCHEMA='<yourdb>'`? `NULL` or not? What's the result of SELECT end_date, NOW() FROM #__anual;` (maybe with a WHERE clause)?

Comment: last_executed = 2014-07-11 00:52:12, Select end_date, NOW()= 2014-07-11 17:53:33. seems that here is the error, end_date is > NOW() so does not delete.

Comment: to set the value for end_date use the following code: end_date="select DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)".

Comment: To shorten it use `UPDATE #__anual SET end_date = NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE WHERE end_date = '2014-07-11 17:53:33'` and you should see it working not long ago.

Comment: @DominicS If you've seen it working we could nearly all comments to my answer :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything is OK.
So much luck for you because this year Germany will win the FIFA WORLD CUP :-p